# Getting Error while setting calendar on edittext onclick

Tags: java, android

I am using button to display the calender.after selecting the date.That date will be displayed on the edittext control.So I displayed the calendar on edit text onclick method.It displays the calendar when i click two times.If i click single time.It allows me to edit.How to get the calendar on single click?

My code is...

```
            billdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(billdate.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Better to use **TextView**.

Comment: @activesince93 Requirement for that screen is Edittext.So I am not able to change the requirement.

Comment: But if you are not able to enter any word or any thing, you should use `TextView`. And set the background like `EditText`.

Comment: android:inputType="none" or billdate.setKeyListener(null); try  this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@activesince93 Thanks for the idea.
I found the solution,changed the EditText control to TextView and set the style like EditText.Now its working fine.I attached what i have did.

```
<TextView
style="@android:style/Widget.EditText"
android:id="@+id/TextView01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
```

Comment: Anyone please make it as answer.because i am unable to do that.

Answer (score 2):

First of all make your editText NonEditable with below xml Attribute

```
android:editable="false"
```

Because of you did not mention your code so I could not found which error you get but I prefer you for try below code for getting calendar and when you select your date It will set in your editText.

```
private Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
public static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd yyyy", Locale.getDefault());

billdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(billdate.getWindowToken(), 0);

            new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                   calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                   calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                   calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                   updateDateUI(calendar, "date");
                }
                }, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show(); }
                });
      }

      protected void updateDateUI(Calendar calendar, String strTimeDate) {
        mEditText.setText(TIME_FORMAT.format(calendar.getTime()));
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for your code buddy.I found the solution by changing the control to TextView.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to disable editing on **EditText** and then make it enable as below:

Set `android:focusable="false"` on your `EditText` and `android:enabled="true"`.

Then implement your `OnClickListener`

But it would be better to use `TextView` in this scenario.